# Laptop froze when updating to Ubuntu 20.4

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, updates, lenovo-laptop, thinkpad

So my laptop froze when updating from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04. I chose the "delete obsolete programs" when updating, do not know if that has to do with anything. Everything installed and downloaded correctly, the PC rebooted and it got stuck in this screen, with the loading logo still going around and around for the last 3 hours. I have tried stuff like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>/<kbd>F2</kbd>/<kbd>F3</kbd>/<kbd>F4</kbd>/<kbd>F5</kbd>/<kbd>F6</kbd> but it does not do anything. Anyone have an idea of what to do? Should I turn it off?

Edit: Laptop is a Lenovo Thinkpad L490

[image: Photo of the screen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First steps of fault finding:

Reset and reboot.
As the computer boots, you will see a Lenovo logo - hit ESC *ONCE* at that time.

If you do this simple task at the correct time; you will end up with the "boot menu" (IDK if that is correct, really).

Now you should find a "recovery mode" option in that menu, select it with the cursor keys and hit ENTER.

Another menu will appear, there is a "fsck" option (mount filesystems read write), select and press enter.

Another option is "activate networking", select and enter.

The last option to use is "drop to root prompt", press enter, and once more to actually get the root prompt.

Now, you are "root" in your new Ubuntu 20.04, and may do anything...

```
# lsblk                          # will tell you what disks and partitions you have  
# dmesg | less                   # will show you the log from the current bootup  
# less /var/log/syslog           # the same as dmesg above
# less /var/log/syslog.1         # yesterdays/previous bootup  
# gunzip < /var/log/syslog.2.gz  # the day before yesterday/(previous^2)
```

**As implied above; To get further, check the log files for errors, faults and other indications of where the actual problem is.**

I assume you know some basics for fault remedies; e.g. `sudo apt install package` to install a missing package... or the reverse `sudo apt purge package` to remove one that fails and is disposable; i.e. not critically required.